# OSX 10.4.11 connected usb dongle to internet but no web access, wifi ok any browser

Tags: usb, browser, macbook, internet-connection, web

I have a macbook running 10.4.11 and can connect to the internet using a BT dongle (ZTEUSB Modem) but cannot access any websites through any browser. I have ditched preference files, in fact anything to do with network connections, uninstalled/reinstalled, updated all software OS etc. you name it but still no joy. I can however connect by Wi-Fi to my home router. Searched high and low and can't find a solution. Please can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

When the dongle has a connection try using terminal with

```
ping 209.85.148.101
```

If you get a reply from google.com your connection is running so you should be able to access google.com using http://209.85.148.101

If this works but you can't access using http://google.com your name resolution is broken.

If ping doesn't give you a reply, your connection is not set up correctly. Try

```
ping <default gateway for dongle-if>
```

you can read out the configured default gateway by opening network config, selecting your dongle click on advanced and then TCP/IP